# Comma Separated List in VBO

Tags: views

I am trying to select a bunch of users with a bulk operation so I can delete them and unpublish their comments. I have a comma separated list of about 250 users. However, when I use the filter command in views, it only lets me enter about 10 names before the form runs out of space.

[image: Views Settings]

Is there something I am missing here? How do I create a filter that will take a much longer list of names? and/or just pass in a CSV file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use contextual links against filters. This is an example view, you can import and check it through admin/structure/views/import: http://paste2.org/p/2282691

Then you need to change , to + (by design, it should work with comma, I haven't idea, why wasn't work for me..) in your source.

I've tested it more than 30 argument passed to view.

Limitations:

- If username contains some 'exotic' char, like @, the view won't have
  result.
- The webserver has url limit (by default 6-700 char as I remember),
  when the url reach it, you'll get apache error.

But both of them happen, if you use normal filter too.

Comment: thanks, this works, but the URL limit is indeed hit way before I would like it to be. I feel there still should be some way to pass in even a very large CSV and use VBO without having to resort to SQL commands, but in absence of that answer using a contextual link works for at least some mass delete purposes.

Answer (score 0):

The textbow must have a size so you wont be able to make more than what your are doing now. But if your in views you can see the DBquery generate and use it on PMA to delete a greater number of users with theirs comments.

Be carefull, it's to do if you know what you are doing. I suggest to look at the query of view  because Drupal create a table for each CCK field so it's hell to figure the inner joins. If you have a doubt, make a save of your database before.